# Autowiring a CsvMapper

Tags: spring, spring-boot, csv, jackson

I use **Jackson** on my Spring Boot application to do JSON serialization/deserialization.

I can autowire the regular ObjectMapper and Spring will automatically register the Jdk8Module and JavaTimeModule.

Now I need to parse and write some **.csv** files. At the moment, when I construct a CsvMapper, I need to manually inject the aforementioned modules:

```
var mapper = new CsvMapper()
            .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

I am wondering if this is really necessary. For the regular ObjectMapper, Spring somehow detects those modules in the classpath and registers them. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring uses the [`Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean.html) to create an `ObjectMapper` bean. Several modules are automatically registered if they are present on the classpath:

- jackson-datatype-jdk7: support for Java 7 types like Path
- jackson-datatype-jdk8: support for other Java 8 types like Optional
- jackson-datatype-jsr310: support for Java 8 Date & Time API types
- jackson-datatype-joda: support for Joda-Time types
- jackson-module-kotlin: support for Kotlin classes and data classes

As far as I know, Spring does not provide a CsvMapper factory bean. Therefore, a `CsvMapper` bean needs to be created manually like you described.